# Step in finding $\sin^{-1}z = w$ for a fixed complex $w$ and unknown complex $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

This is in the section of the book preceding a general formula but I don't know how the author arrives to the second equation in the picture. The closes I have gotten to it is
$$2iz = e^{iw}(1-e^{-1})$$
but I don't see how I can get an $(e^{iw})^2$ term without also having a $z^2$ term.

Comment: You have a mistake where you write $e^{-1}$. I believe this should clarify the 2nd form.

Comment: @JonathanY.: Good catch on my typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$z=\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{2i}$$ can be rewritten (through some arithmetic) as $$e^{iw}-2iz-e^{-iw}=0.$$ Now, multiply by the non-zero quantity $e^{iw}$ to get $$(e^{iw})^2-2iz(e^{iw})-1=0,$$ as desired.